# Calculating the time difference between two datetime values in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to compare two date and times with each other and then use that information for other stuff. Like `if delta > 23` hours do this, `elif delta > 11` hours, do that etc. I thought this would be a reasonable way to write it, but python won't accept it! It says:

```
ValueError: 'h' is a bad directive in format '%m/%d/%Y%h:%m:%s'
```

Isn't `h` the standard way to write hours in Python? :o

My dates are written in this format: "12/28/13 16:49:19", "m/d/y h:m:s" if that's any help!

```
from datetime import datetime
date_format = "%m/%d/%Y%h:%m:%s"
then=(dictionary["date"])
now= time.strftime("%c")
a = datetime.strptime(str(then), date_format)
b = datetime.strptime(str(now), date_format)
delta = b - a
print(delta.hour)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 24 hour format is `%H`, a capital H, not a lowercase. The same for the minutes and seconds. You'll need a space as well, and you have a year format *without* the century, so use lower-case `y`:

```
date_format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"
```

See the [`strftime()` and `strptime()` behaviour documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). `%h` doesn't exist as a format character.

And instead of using `time.strftime('%c')` to represent *now*, then parse that again, use:

```
b = datetime.now()
```

`datetime.timedelta` objects do not **have** an `hours` attribute; calculate the hours from the total seconds in the delta:

```
delta = b - a
print(delta.total_seconds() // 60)
```

or compare the `delta` object against another `timedelta()`:

```
if delta > timedelta(hours=23):
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"
>>> datetime.strptime('12/28/13 16:49:19', date_format)
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 28, 16, 49, 19)
```

Comment: Why would you truncate hours with `//`? You could use `/` (float division) or compare using `delta > timedelta(hours=23)`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: because I'd view hours as a whole number. I like the `timedelta(hours=23)` idea though.

Comment: If hours is a whole number then `delta > 23` from the question that you are trying to answer doesn't make sense (datetime accepts hours in 0..23 (including)).